# pkgloader is not finding l3regex

Tags: l3regex

I would like to try a package which seems interesting, but it some dependencies are not satisfied.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pkgloader}
\LoadPackagesNow

\begin{document}
    pckloader trial
\end{document}
```

And I get the following error: `! LaTeX Error: File 'l3regex.sty' not found.`. Therefore, I tried to update my distribution with the linux commands

```
tlmgr update --self
tlmgr update --all
```

But the package `l3regex` is still not foundable. Plus, my computer is not lying since `l3regex.sty` is not in my folder `/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*`.

So, is it something normal ? How can I workaround this problem ?

Comment: Write the package author, he should correct the package - l3regex is now part of expl3 and should no longer be loaded separately.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Comment: I've logged https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-pkgloader/pull/25: there are also issues in `withargs` that need addressing ...

Comment: l3regex is not longer experimental and therefore part of the l3kernel. Try to actualize the repository for your MikeTex distribution.

Answer (score 10):

Stand-alone `l3regex` was folded into the `expl3` core some time ago. We've now withdrawn the 'stub' `l3regex.sty` file, so `pkgloader` needs to be updated. For the present, you could add

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@l3regex.sty\endcsname{}
```

before trying to load `pkgloader` to 'fool it' into thinking `l3regex` is loaded as a separate file.

Comment: That won't help. The package has more expl3 problems, e.g. quite a lot ! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'nncn'.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I'd just tried to solve the issue at hand ...