# l3kernel is installed, but can't find l3regex?

Tags: expl3, latex3, l3regex

I'm trying to use a very jury-rigged (and probably totally irreproducible, sorry) build process to get my moderncv cv to build on Netlify.  Netlify doesn't officially support tex builds, but someone [came up with a way to do so](https://github.com/frangio/netlify-latex) using a complicated bash script that does a minimal installation of texlive and then uses texliveonfly to fetch packages.  This process is failing largely because it can't get ahold of something called `l3regex.sty`

But this is the mysterious part. See, I've edited the script in that repository to add a bunch of tlmgr commands in order to get the stuff that my build keeps failing on.  Right now, I have:

```
tlmgr update -self -all
tlmgr install l3packages
tlmgr install etoolbox
tlmgr install xcolor
tlmgr install microtype
tlmgr install l3kernel
tlmgr install xpackages
tlmgr install regexpatch
```

[According to CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3regex), l3regex is part of l3kernel.  But when I try to install l3kernel, I get:

`tlmgr install: package already present: l3kernel`

yet when it actually tries to build, it still throws an error `Latexmk: Missing input file: 'l3regex.sty'`

There's also a SO from about a year ago [claiming that l3regex is part of expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468973/pkgloader-is-not-finding-l3regex).  So, I tried to install that too, but it said `tlmgr install: package expl3 not present in repository`, which I guess makes sense, because [CTAN says that one is part of l3kernel too](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3).

But I've got l3kernel installed!  So why can't tex find l3regex?

And is there just somewhere that I can straight-up download l3regex.sty to put it on the search path and have done with it, rather than fight with package management for days?

Comment: `expl3` is a LaTeX package that is present in the CTAN package `l3kernel`. In a way, both posts you linked are correct. And yes, `l3regex` is now part of `expl3`. I'd say you have some old code that manually loads `l3regex` with `\usepackage{l3regex}`. You can simply delete that line or, to be sure, replace it by `\usepackage{expl3}`.

Comment: oooh thank you @PhelypeOleinik ---that got me a little bit further into the nest of latex errors at least. :-)

Comment: Great :-) I'll mark this as a duplicate, if that's okay.